# How to connect Eris to different accounts to start a chain?

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment, eris-industries

I wanted to start a blockchain on my computer. For this, I am using Eris. I activated different accounts like root, validator, and participant account using `eris chains start <ChainName> --init-dir <DIR> --publish` this created different accounts on different ports on my machine. But now I have no idea how to connect them so that the chain is running and creating blocks.
I thought of using `eris chains ls -a` to get the mapped ports but then what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect the chains, you need to fill in the `seeds` field in the `config.toml` file. That field takes a string and the format of the field should be: `seedIP1:seedPort1,seedIP2:seedPort2`. So if you had three validators running on standard ports with the IPs of `111.111.111.111`, `222.222.222.222` and `333.333.333.333` then your seeds field would look like this:

`seeds = "111.111.111.111:46656,222.222.222.222:46656,333.333.333.333:46656"`

One gotcha is to not have spaces within the string field.

Comment: I had one more doubt on starting a chain. It is mentioned on the Monax website [Chain deploying documentation](https://monax.io/docs/documentation/cm/latest/examples/chain-deploying/) that we copy config.toml file from default to chain folder `cp ../default/config.toml .` The problem here is the default folder is empty. The folder gets created if it is not present when I use 'make' a chain. So in place of config.toml from the default should I use config.toml from one of the accounts folder?

Comment: Yes indeed they will all be the same.